# CM bootstraper showing a window before the root view

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper where I use `OnStartup()` to check a view things and call `DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>` later. In some scenarios I must have the user to make an important decision or show some warning before the root view launches. I can do this by using `WindowManager.ShowDialog()`.

But here is the problem: When I have no window shown before the root view, all works like expected.

When I show a window before the root view the `DisplayRootViewFor()` call is made but the application terminate immediately.

I guess this is because when I use the window manager to show a window before it gets the root view and closing it makes the WPF application thinking its main window is closed and it terminates automatically.

So how can I show a (modal) window before the root view?

---

I found one possible solution is:

Set `Application.ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown`. Then I have to track when really shutting down the application like when the shell is closed I have to call `System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();` explicitly.

I am curious if there is also another way but I guess when the modal window is closed the for a moment the number of windows in the WPF application goes down to 0 the shutdown is triggered regardless if a new main window is established shortly after.

Comment: How about showing that Dialog in the OnInitialize()  of the main ViewModel?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is that an implicitly called method?

Comment: Yes, when your VM derives from Screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your shutdown on your shell view on close as the shell view is the main window if the user close it means they want to close the exe.

```
private void ShellView_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: That would be subscribing to an event in code-behind, not in the way Caliburn.Micro handles MVVM.

Comment: if that is a concern you can put it in deactive
        protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
        {
            if (close)
            {
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
            base.OnDeactivate(close);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone else is having this problem, I solved it overriding the OnActivate method like this:

```c#
protected override void OnActivate()
        {
            _windowManager.ShowDialog(YOUR_WINDOW);
            base.OnActivate();
        }
```

Thus you don't have to set ***Application.ShutdownMode*** to ***OnExplicitShutdown*** and your application works normally.